# JS: How to convert 2345 in to 2.345,00?

Tags: javascript, numbers, converters, notation

how do i convert  2345 in to 2.345,00 the right way?

converting 2345 in to 2345.00 is easy as:

```
var new = parseFloat('2345').toFixed(2);
```

Have i to work with substrings or are there functions for formating floats in to UK notation?

Comment: Don't use `new` keyword like that

Comment: Best Answer so far: http://stackoverflow.com/a/149107/2099411